# Best way to test if a variable is nil or false implicitly

Tags: ruby

I was hoping someone could help me with identifying the most idiomatic way to test if a variable is nil or false implicitly for the sake of readability.

Here is my explicit example:

```
if somevar.nil? # explicitly checking for nil.
  puts "Its nil."
end
```

Is it better to write:

```
if !somevar # implicit
  puts "Var is nil or false."
end
```

I really like this way:

```
if not somevar # implicit
  puts "Var is nil or false"
end
```

From what I am reading, testing for `nil` explicitly should be avoided to some extent as its generally not needed. Most examples suggest to take action only if a variable exists. However, I want to perform an action when a variable does not exist.

Main inspiration for ditching nil came from: [ruby_idioms](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def truthiness(value)
  if value
    "truthy"
  else
    "falsy"
  end
end

puts "nil:",   truthiness(nil)    # falsy
puts "false:", truthiness(false)  # falsy
puts "true:",  truthiness(true)   # truthy
puts "[]:",    truthiness([])     # truthy
puts "{}:",    truthiness({})     # truthy
puts "0:",     truthiness(0)      # truthy
```

I know you know Python, so I can say that:

In Python, None, False, and empty containers such as [], {}, and even 0 are all falsy.

In Ruby, nil and false are falsy, whereas most other things are truthy, even [], {}, and 0.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most idiomatic way in ruby for testing whether something is `false` or `nil` is using `unless`:

```
unless somevar
  puts "Var is nil or false."
end
```

From the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

> Favor `unless` over `if` for negative conditions (or control flow
>   `||`).
>
> ```
> # bad
> do_something if !some_condition
>
> # bad
> do_something if not some_condition
>
> # good
> do_something unless some_condition
>
> # another good option
> some_condition || do_something
> ```

Comment: This is a great solution as well. I was starting to head down this path, however I didn't see much precedence for it in practice for this particular use case (looking at others code, books, etc.).  Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) keyword :

> `defined?` expression tests whether or not expression refers to anything recognizable (literal object, **local variable that has been initialized**, method name visible from the current scope, etc.). **The return value is nil if the expression cannot be resolved**. Otherwise, the return value provides information about the expression.

```
unless defined?(var)
   #your code
end
```

Quick PRY to test, what the `defined?` returns when a variable is defined and when not :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> pry
[1] pry(main)> defined?(x)
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> x = nil
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> defined? x
=> "local-variable"
[4] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Agreed. Sorry.. I used the word defined in my comments loosely. I am more interested in finding if a variable is false or nil implicitly vs. explicitly for the sake of readability. Thank you for your feedback.. Will +1 this as this may help me solve a specific use case in the future.

Comment: @user2152283 For `nil`... You can call `#nil?` method... better use `!!var == true`.. or `!!var == false`..(whatever you like).

Comment: Thanks for the added insight. This is great info.